# Getting an error when I try to assign a char array via the constructor

Tags: c++

I want to pass a char array to my constructor and initialize the member variable `field`, but I get the following error:

> error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char [255]'

```
class C
{
    char field[255];

public:
    C(char field[255])
    {
        this->field=field;
    }
};
```

Comment: I recommend using different names between your constructor and function arguments and your data members.  Makes life easier.

Comment: Also, prefer using `std::string` instead of `char` arrays.  Arrays can overflow.  The `std::string` can be passed by reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign/copy an array like that in c++. Instead, you could use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to do a copy of the array, in the constructor:

```
C(char f[255])
{
  std::copy(f, f + 255, field);
}
```

I suggest using [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) instead of `char[255]`. Then your class simply becomes:

```
class C
{
  std::string field;
 public:
  C(std::string field) : field(std::move(field)) {}
};
```

This way you don't have to worry about the array being large enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can't copy an C array with the assignment operator but C++ provides `std::array`:

```
class C
{
    std::array<char, 255> field;

public:
    C(const std::array<char, 255> &field) : field(field) {}
};
```

If you can use dynamic memory allocation and the size of the field can also be dynamic you should prefer `std::string`:

```
class C
{
    std::string field;

public:
    C(const std::string &field) : field(field) {}
};
```

Comment: The C++ language provides other opportunities, such as `std::string` and `std::vector<char>`.  I recommend `std::string`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm trying to make my answer as similar as possible. There is no dynamic memory allocation in the question so I avoid it if possible. This could be code for an embedded system like an Arduino. Sometimes it makes sense to avoid `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

In a function parameter, a `char[]` (with or without a number specified) is just *syntax sugar* for a `char*` pointer.  And you can't initialize a `char[]` array with a `char*` pointer, hence the compiler error.

For what you are attempting, you must copy the memory that the `char*` is pointing at, eg:

```cpp
class C
{
    char field[255];

public:
    C(char field[255]) // aka C(char *field)
    {
        memcpy(this->field, field, 255);
        // or: std::copy(field, field+255, this->field);
        // or: std::copy_n(field, 255, this->field);
    }
};
```

Alternatively, if you want to ensure the caller can only pass in a `char[255]`, pass it by *reference* instead of by *pointer*:

```cpp
class C
{
    char field[255];

public:
    C(const char (&field)[255])
    {
        memcpy(this->field, field, 255);
        // or: std::copy(field, field+255, this->field);
        // or: std::copy_n(field, 255, this->field);
    }
};
```

That being said, you should consider using [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead, then you can use `operator=` assignment like you want:

```cpp
#include <array>

using Char255Array = std::array<char, 255>;

class C
{
    Char255Array field;

public:
    C(const Char255Array &field)
    {
        this->field = field;
    }
};
```

Or better, use the constructor's [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor):

```cpp
#include <array>

using Char255Array = std::array<char, 255>;

class C
{
    Char255Array field;

public:
    C(const Char255Array &field)
        : field(field)
    {
    }
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Raw arrays are not recommended to use in c++, you can read about vectors and arrays classes they are more usefull. Although the solution for your problem is you just need to change the type of the attribute field to char*, and it works perfectly.
    for more explanation:
 in c++, you can assign to a char* type a char array but the reverse is impossible because the pointer is only pointing on the first character.

```
class C
{
    char* field;

public:
    C(char field[255])
    {
        this->field=field;
    }
};
```

Comment: He will point at the first character of the char array given in the parameters of the constructor in this case he will be pointing at field[0] memory adress

Comment: But where did that memory come from? Did someone do `new`? Who's supposed to do `delete`?

Comment: In the main method when the instance is created, then we can call the constructor with `new`

Comment: And who calls `delete`? What happens when a `C` object is copied? There are many potential issues here, and is not good advice to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: I think it's an easy solution that can help him to keep working with the char type instead of string, because having a pointer that point on the same is string is much more optimized than having two char arrays with the same information in the memory, after he can add a destructor to call `delete` method. This is my point of view. He can choose whatever solution he want after all

Comment: If you're going to provide an answer with caveats and holes in the logic, you owe it to future questioners to outline and explain those caveats and provide advice on how to avoid the holes.